# Overriding description method for NSObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm not sure if this is a simulator issue, but I don't remeber having  this problem before when I was using the iPad 5.0 simulator and below (now I'm running iPad 5.1 simulator).  I overrode the description method for my Condition object to be:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Condition: %@", _conditionName];
    return [str autorelease];
}
```

I have an array of these objects.  My values are all valid.  When I do:

```
for (Condition *p in self.reportsArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [p description]);
}
```

It logs all my values, and then it crashes at the end.  When I look at Instruments with Zombies, the last 4 calls are

```
-[NSPlaceHolderString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]
+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]
-[NSAutoreleasePool release]
-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
```

Am I overriding description correctly?

Edit:
In Instruments, I get: message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address:0x8ccf190.  On the app itself, I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Why don't you migrate to ARC?

Comment: Is `_conditionName` a valid Objective-C object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the string returned from your description method is being released too soon.

Try rewriting your method using the `stringWithFormat:` class method.

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Condition: %@", _conditionName];
}
```

Comment: This is what I always do, never have a problem.

Comment: @jonkroll That is interesting though since I thought that alloc]init]autorelease would be the same as returning an autoreleased NSString?

Comment: @Crystal: honestly I thought so too.  I'll admit I don't fully understand what is happening in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure _conditionName is not a primitive.
Because the format string "%@" expects an object.